# Passing arguments between parent application and OSGi Framework

Tags: java, frameworks, arguments, osgi, equinox

I have to pass parameters between parent application and embeded OSGi. I use equinox and run OSGi by FrameworkFactory in my Launcher class, then I install and start bundles. It is possible to pass object reference or even some primitive type to bundle or service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After launching the framework, you can get the system bundle context and access and call services registered by bundles in the framework. Care must be taken about the service types since the are likely loaded from bundles and thus the types are not directly visible to your launching code. But you can use reflection. Or you can put those types in the framework classloader and export them from the system bundle via [org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA) framework property your launcher sets.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it is not solution of my problem. I want to run a bundle or service with specific argument (e.g. object-reference) from my parent application class (which will be launcher of the OSGi Framework). You are talking about sending whole class to the system bundle by system_packages_extra to have a visibility of it in OSGi Framework - I don't need it (i resolve it by adding classes which i need to osgi classpath as bundle).

Comment: Can I use reflection to run service method from launcher class with parameters? But how I can get the Service class name outside of the OSGi Framework?

Comment: You can use reflection to invoke a method on a service whose type is not visible to you in the launcher. You can pass any argument type which you can create either directly or via reflection.

Comment: Can You give me an example? I don't know how i can get the Service class name to create it via reflection
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("BundleService");
I tried this:
        Bundle[] bundles = ctx.getBundles();
  
  for (Bundle bun : bundles){
   
   System.out.println(bun.getClass());
  
                }

But it doesn't work... I got only org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost class

Comment: You can just use a String constant for the class name: "org.foo.BundleService".

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bundleservice.BundleService
 at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:139)
 at RunEquinoxOsgi.main(RunEquinoxOsgi.java:118)

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. First I starting equinox 

BundleContext ctx = org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup( args, null );

Next I installing and starting bundles like this:

Bundle b6 = ctx.installBundle("file:C:\\service.jar");
  System.out.println(b6.getBundleId() + " installed");
b6.start();

Comment: And then I trying to get the service class Class c = Class.forName("com.bundleservice.BundleService");
I have an activator which starts services and it's works fine, but i have to call it from java application.

Comment: You do not need to load the class to use the service. Use the service API that takes a String of the class name. e.g. http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getServiceReference(java.lang.String). Then get the service object: http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getService(org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference). Then use reflection to call methods on the object since you go not have visibility to the service type.

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution and patience! :-) It's very usefull.